# Sequential Subsets of a list

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Given a list say

```
{"a", "b", "c", "d"}
```

Is there any easier way to generate list of sequential subsets like this (order of the result is not important)

```
{
 {"a"},
 {"a b"},
 {"a b c"},
 {"a b c d"},
 {"b"},
 {"b c"},
 {"b c d"},
 {"c"},
 {"c d"},
 {"d"}
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think I like this best of all:

```
set = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};

ReplaceList[set, {___, x__, ___} :> {x}]
```

With the string joining:

```
ReplaceList[set, {___, x__, ___} :> "" <> Riffle[{x}, " "]]
```

In a similar vein, specific to strings:

```
StringCases["abcd", __, Overlaps -> All]
```

---

Since Nasser says I am cheating, here is a more manual approach that also has greater efficiency on large sets:

```
ClearAll[f, f2]
f[i_][x_] := NestList[i, x, Length@x - 1]
f2[set_]  := Join @@ ( f[Most] /@ f[Rest][set] )

f2[{"a", "b", "c", "d"}]
```

Comment: +1, that is not fair Mr Wizard, you are letting Mathematica do all the hard work using this method. You are supposed to do something !

Comment: This is great! and I think it's a great accordance with Mathematica's core conception rather than a cheating :)

Comment: Neat!!! If you use your two `NestList` functions inside the following form `StringJoin @@@ (f[Most]/@f[Rest]@set // Flatten[#, 1] &) // Partition[#, 1] & // InputForm` you get the desired output

Comment: @rcollyer I am amused at which of my answers get a lot of votes; this one seemed fairly obvious to me, while some that I thought were really clever struggled to get two or three.

Comment: I think the obvious, but clever ones get the most votes. The ones that are clever, but less obvious, tend to generate less votes because the bar is a bit higher for understanding. I have trouble understanding some of Leonid's and I hesitate to upvote an answer I don't comprehend.

Comment: @rcollyer I have the same problem with Leonid's answers; I have about a dozen bookmarked that I need to review, both for my own education, and so that I may upvote with confidence.

Answer (score 14):

```
Flatten[Partition[{a, b, c, d}, #, 1] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4}, 1]
```

gives

> {{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}, {a, b}, {b, c}, {c, d}, {a, b, c}, {b, c, d}, {a,
>   b, c, d}}

Answer (score 7):

How about this:

```
origset = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};

bdidxset = Subsets[Range[4], {1, 2}]

origset[[#[[1]] ;; #[[-1]]]] & /@ bdidxset
```

which gives

```
{{"a"}, {"b"}, {"c"}, {"d"}, {"a", "b"}, {"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "b", 
  "c", "d"}, {"b", "c"}, {"b", "c", "d"}, {"c", "d"}}
```

Answer (score 5):

I like TomD's method better, but this is what came to my mind, sans string processing:

```
set = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};

n = Length@set;

Join @@ Table[set~Take~{s, f}, {s, n}, {f, s, n}] // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @yoda I thought the answers were of sufficiently different character.  I see a problem with omnibus answers: it is not clear *which* method people are voting for, devaluing the purpose of votes, and voters may feel they have to vote for methods they do not like (or outright fail) if they want to vote for one they do.  Contrary to Peter's assertion I was not gaming votes.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I know, and I didn't pay heed to Peter's comment. I know that you do this for sufficiently different answers, but I was curious why here, when you seem to have clubbed two different styles in the other answer. I later realized that this was the first answer and you probably added the edit to that one to keep close to Nasser's comment. In any case, I don't really care – just curious.

Comment: @yoda I posted a question in the lounge; I want to know what the community thinks about this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
a = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
b = List[StringJoin[Riffle[#, " "]]] & /@
  Flatten[Table[c = Drop[a, n];
    Table[Take[c, i], {i, Length[c]}],
    {n, 0, Length[a]}], 1]
```

the output will look like this:

```
{{"a"}, {"a b"}, {"a b c"}, {"a b c d"}, {"b"}, {"b c"}, {"b c d"}, {"c"}, {"c d"}, {"d"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution

```
a={"a","b","c","d"};
StringJoin@Riffle[#, " "] & /@ 
  DeleteDuplicates[
   LongestCommonSubsequence[a, #] & /@ 
    DeleteCases[Subsets@a, {}]] // Column
```

Result

```
a
b
c
d
a b
b c
c d
a b c
b c d
a b c d
```

Answer (score 1):

one way:

```
makeList[lst_] := Map[ Union[lst[[1 ;; #]]] &, Range@Length[lst]]
r = Map[makeList[lst[[# ;; -1]]] &, Range@Length[lst]];
Flatten[r, 1]
```

gives

```
{{"a"}, 
 {"a", "b"}, 
 {"a", "b", "c"}, 
 {"a", "b", "c", "d"}, 
 {"b"},
 {"b", "c"},
 {"b", "c", "d"},
 {"c"}, 
 {"c", "d"}, 
 {"d"}}
```